# How is the below question highlighted with a background shade?

Tags: discussion, design, keyboard-shortcuts

When I was navigating to a question and entering comments, I incorrectly pressed some key near the Enter key and the question I was commenting in gets highlighted. When I inspect element the highlighted element block, I noticed the `keyboard-selected` class added to the `question` class div element. What is the use of the option and using which key I can make the div highlight like this,

> [image]

Comment: Duplicate of [What is the black box around a post when using the comment keyboard shortcut (c)?](/q/260191/289905).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pressed the <kbd>U</kbd> key, as can be seen in the keyboard shortcuts help screen: (by pressing <kbd>?</kbd>)

> [image]

This is useful for cases where you select some answer (by pressing <kbd>J</kbd> or <kbd>K</kbd>), and want to select the question again. All actions (vote, edit, comment, etc) are done on the selected post, or the question if no post is selected.